# How to insert two tables having same primary key?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables say Table A and Table B. Both have same columns and column  'cid' has primary Key and it's auto_incremented. 
Now i have to insert Table A into Table B but i need data of both tables into Table B.
How can i insert Table A into Table B ??

Comment: Please add example data and expected output

Comment: `insert into TableB (select * from TableA);`

Comment: i am using single query to insert multiple tables into their respective backup tables...but now problem is that it does not allow to insert records as both tables have same primary key column. Is there any way to do it through same query. Query is:
INSERT INTO $backup_tbl_name SELECT * FROM $tbl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

INSERT INTO TableB ("Column 1 of Table B", "column 2 of Table B", , ,etc) (SELECT "Column 1 of Table A", "column 2 of Table A", , ,etc FROM TableA)

The above query will insert the Values of Table A into Table B. Do not include the column cid in the column list(since it is auto-incremented).

Comment: i am using single query to insert multiple tables into their respective backup tables...but now problem is that it does not allow to insert records as both tables have same primary key column. Is there any way to do it through same query. Query is: INSERT INTO $backup_tbl_name SELECT * FROM $tbl

Comment: Its urgently required ..please help me out..Need to insert one table into another with same schema and same primary key only through single query. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue by doing following thing, hope it may be useful to anyone too.

The cause of the problem is that the parent table and its corresponding backup table have same schema so whenever Restore process is took place it just encounter a problem due to same primary key on both tables.
Hence to overcome it, backup table has to be modified by using ALTER query. And in modification a  new column 'ID' is added to all backup tables using :

```
ALTER TABLE $backup_tbl_name ADD `id` BIGINT unsigned NOT NULL   AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Auto increment field for backup table.' PRIMARY KEY
```

and making this newly added column Primary key of backup table.

And at last INSERT query has to be modified as well as during insertion newly added column also has to be pass. And it modified as:

```
INSERT INTO $backup_tbl_name SELECT * , NULL FROM $tbl;
```